# Does ruby on rails have issues with regards to max # of threads the server and serve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. Does ruby on rails have issues with regards to max # of threads the server and serve?

i.e. you have to run multiple instances of the server if you reach high load?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby-on-rails is by design single-threaded. To be able to server multiple users efficiently there are several solutions:

- use [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) and [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/)
- use a cluster of mongrel services, for which loads of alternatives exist (mongrel-cluster, or using apache, nginx, ... to dispatch to different mongrels)

Does that help?

Comment: I see, so is this single-threaded nature different than in asp.net or java?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not know enough of those platforms to compare. But to my knowledge, in java the application server is multi-threaded, and your own code has to be written accordingly (using thread-safe types, e.g. Vector and not ArrayList). In ASP.NET i do not know. Maybe you should ask a new question for this.
In my opinion the programmer productivity/pleasure largely outways the possible cons of performance (which is perfectly solveable and for which better solutions are being created all the time). But it depends on the type of application you want to build.